# Accessing data inside a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want to access information inside a struct if somebody can help me out here.

```
typedef struct {        
    int time;       
    char sat,rcv;  
    char LLI [3];
} obsd_t;


typedef struct {                
    obsd_t *data;      
} obs_t;
```

I have something like

```
obs_t obs;
int x;
```

Now I want to assign x to the value of time in obsd_t so what should I do. Is something like this correct

```
x=obs.data.time;
```

p.s I looked over other threads of stackoverflow but could not understand from there. Some did not have any accepted answer so I was reluctant

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are mixing a pointer with a variable. Use `.` operator for struct variables (e.g. obs) and use `->` for pointers (e.g. for data)

i.e.

`x = obs.data->time`

or you can also use like this as suggested by *Yu Hao*

`x = obs.(*data).time`

Comment: You can learn more about pointers at [this site](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).

Answer (score 5):

You should use this instead:

```
x = obs.data->time;
```

because `data` in `obs_t` is a pointer.

In general, assume `strcut foo* p;`, then to access element `bar` in `struct foo`

```
(*p).bar
```

and

```
p->bar
```

are the same

Answer (score 4):

You just need to do it like this:

```
x=obs.data->time;
```

(This assumes of course that you have initialised `obs.data` to point at a valid instance of `obsd_t`.)

Answer (score 3):

`data` is a pointer to a `obsd_t` struct. You have to use the operator `->` instead of `.` to access the elements of a structure referenced by a pointer:

```
x = obs.data->time;
```

Answer (score 2):

Access to the `data` as a **pointer** to a struct using `->` operator:

```
x = obs.data->time;
```

or

Access to the **address** of the `data` using `*` operator (**dereferencing the pointer**):

```
x = obs.(*data).time
```

Both variants are right.

Read this for more detailes: [Pointers and Structures](http://www.taranets.net/cgi/ts/1.37/ts.ws.pl?w=329;b=282)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the struct like this: `x=obs.data.time;` you have to declare your `obs_t` differently, like that:

```
typedef struct {                
    obsd_t data;      
} obs_t;
```

Please familiarize yourself with how pointers work so that you can avoid such problems in the future.